# Running several Google Colab Notebooks at the same time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

If I run several Google Colab Notebooks (runtimes) at the same time, is the perfomance shared?
I have a big dataframe to operate on so I decided to split it and let the code run on each part on a different notebook. However it seems to take as long as it would take on the whole thing in one.

Is there any information on that?

Answer (score 0):

Each Colab notebook uses a distinct virtual machine backend in order to perform computations. From a performance perspective, each notebook will be isolated from the activity of distinct notebooks.

In order to offer more useful guidance, please share a self-contained example that shows, with code, what you are doing and the performance bottleneck you observe.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was in the same situation and I think it saved me a lot of time. I had to process documents and find terms in the document to create an [Inverted Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). It took me around 6-8 hours and had to keep my laptop running overnight. Then I tried splitting the dataset into 5 sub-tasks [image: 5 sub-tasks]
and the task completed in nearly 3.5 hours.
See actual time taken here [image: See actual time taken here]